# Async false for shorthand AJAX get request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the following ajax get function to check the status of a user. Is it possible to set `async: false` with this shorthand method? If not how can this be changed so that I can add async false?

```
$.get("/submit/checkuser/", function (userStatus) {
    if (userStatus == 'Disabled') { // check if user if disabled                    

    } else if (userStatus == 'Deleted') { // check if user if deleted

    } else {

    };
}).fail(function () {                
    connectionError();
});
```

Comment: You have all the information needed on this page : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This might work for you

```
$.ajax({
    url : "/submit/checkuser/",
    type : "get",
    async: false,
    success : function(userStatus) {
       if (userStatus == 'Disabled') { // check if user if disabled                    
       } else if (userStatus == 'Deleted') { // check if user if deleted
       } else {
       };
    },
    error: function() {
       connectionError();
    }
 });
```

Comment: This should not be the correct answer as per the question which emphasizes **SHORTHAND** see @Stryner answer  http://stackoverflow.com/a/25489055/1226748

Answer (score 23):

The only way to make a synchronous `$.get` call is to set ajaxSetup to synchronous:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:false});
```

This is considered bad form though, since it affects every ajax call made by JQuery on the page. I would suggest just biting the bullet and using the more elaborate `jQuery.ajax` syntax.

See [How can I get jQuery to perform a synchronous, rather than asynchronous, Ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re) for a fuller discussion.

Comment: can we just reset the setup back to `async:true` after the `$.get`?

Comment: @DarielPratama You could. Since Javascript is single-threaded, that should work without any issues.

Comment: I upvoted this answer, though people should know that at least with version 3.1, you get a warning "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/." in the console every time you make a synchronous ajax call.

Comment: This is bad because it sets async to false for every request afterwards as well, which might not be desired.

Answer (score 7):

From above though, I use it like this

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:false});

  // my code 

jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:true});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
$.get('/your/url/dot/com', { async: false }, function(data){
    globalBaseURL = data;
});
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a form of [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) that accepts an object for options as the second parameter... it appears to only have the two signatures - i.e.`jQuery.get( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )` and `jQuery.get( [settings ] )` so with your example, `{ async: false }` would be treated as data sent to the request...

Answer (score 0):

Use `jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:false});` because `$.get()` is Jquery shorthand method with syntax `jQuery.get( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )` and to make changes to setting there is `jQuery.get( [settings ] )`